# Kendo Multiselect added a filed multiple time

Tags: c#, angularjs, kendo-grid, kendo-multiselect

when I select a category then category related data will load into select element which is created by Kendo this (getCOBKendoDDList() ) method so when ever I select category it generated the select element but my problem is it's generated another one too which I don't want.. I want only create single select element and data will only updated in that single select element when I select the category (Risk,Claim,Premium) I also uploaded the images

```
    getCOBKendoDDList = () => {
        $("#COB").kendoMultiSelect({
            dataTextField: "Text",
            dataValueField: "Value",
            filter: 'contains',
            dataSource: this.$scope.classOfBusinessList
        });
        var multiSelect = $("#COB").data("kendoMultiSelect");
        var value = multiSelect.value();
        multiSelect.value(this.$scope.SelectedClassOfBusiness);
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="fg-line" id="ClassOfBusinessParent" ng-class="{'errorBorder': (SelectedClassOfBusiness.length == 0 && clickedNext)}">
                                            <select id="COB"
                                                    ng-model="SelectedClassOfBusiness" ng-change="getloadData(SelectedCategory)"
                                                    class="full-width m-b form-control" required />
                                        </div>
```

**Problem Definition**

`getCOBKendoDDList()` this method is call when category get selected (Risk,premium,claims) and this method responsible for generate the dynamic select element

**step one** select Risk load the data related Risk and display successfully in dynamically generated (select element )[steponeimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJtix.png)

**step two** select premium load the data but another select element is created that I don't want thats is Risk and premium both (select element) is created [steptwoimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvljU.png)

Comment: I'm a little confused.. Your problem definition doesn't really explain the problem, just the desired functionality. What is the actual issue? Or do you need guidance on how to create [cascading multiselects](http://dojo.telerik.com/igImE)?

Comment: when i select a category then category related data will load into select  which is created by Kendo this (getCOBKendoDDList()  ) method  so whenere i select category it genrated the another select element which i dont want.. i want only create single select element and data willl only updated in that single select element

Comment: The link provided in the first comment is what you want. If you want to limit the number of selections made in a multiselect control, you can use [`maxSelectedItems`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#configuration-maxSelectedItems)

Comment: how we can use ?

Comment: but this is for item

Comment: No....maxSelectedItems: 1 is not working it again genreating another select element tab like  steptwoimage

Comment: i want onlye to generate single select element and on next move it only  require update the single select

Comment: Can you provide a snippet using Dojo of the problem? Will make it much easier to debug and solve. For now, try moving your multiselect initialisation into the document.ready; I think the issue may be that you are initialising the widget multiple times (every time `getCOBKendoDDList` is called), and then inside `getCOBKendoDDList` you can use [`setDataSource`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/multiselect#methods-setDataSource)